# Compatibility issues between jquery libraries

Tags: jquery

I am using some jquery in my code:

```
$('li.dropdown-toggle').on('hover', function () {
    $(this).find(".submenu").slideToggle(400);
});
```

It works fine when I link to 1.7.2 jquery library (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js).

Unfortunately the website needs 3.1.0 library (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js).

How can I modify the code without swapping libraries to make sure it works fine?

[just in case, here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/z58c63Lt/32/) - it works ok in this fiddle, but when I change the library to 3+ it stops working

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes

> Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave.

Simply replace `.on('hover', function() { ... })` with `.on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {...})`.

Comment: @cale_b why?? any reason for that?

Comment: @AdamNajlepszy In general, I agree with cale_b (although maybe not in this specific instance). We don't want to clutter up StackOverflow with multiples of the same question, and by answering clear duplicates, we encourage more of them.

Comment: @TylerRoper, thanks. Will keep in mind. Thanks